# Rationale for system calls that allow request of size_t but result of only ssize_t?

Tags: c, linux, unix

Consider:

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

The result has to be signed to account for -1 on error, etc., and is thus ssize_t.  But why then allow for the request to be an unsigned amount (twice as large) when the result of asking for more than ssize_t is undefined?

Is there a significant optimization in the kernel by virtue of not checking for signedness of the count parameter?  Or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) for `ssize_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte)`

> If the value of nbyte is greater than {SSIZE_MAX}, the result is implementation-defined.

So each particular implementation may handle this situation differently. I would not be surprised if some implementations simply set `EFBIG`.

As for the rationale, perhaps `size_t` is simply the best type to represent the size of the buffer, semantically? It states that this argument is a nonnegative size, and nothing else.

Comment: It would be better to link to the current version of the standard.

Comment: size_t is also the result type of `sizeof(Buffer)`, presumably used to compute the parameter's value.

Comment: @R..; @Cubbi: the POSIX.1-2008 Standard can be found at [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Answer (score 5):

I think it's nice, since `size_t` is the type of the value returned by the `sizeof` operator, this allows calls like this:

```
char buffer[1 << 20];
ssize_t wrote;

wrote = write(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer);
```

If the function took the signed version, a cast would be required. Also, as others have pointed out, semantically functions like these *cannot* accept a negative value, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to accept them.

Comment: A cast most certainly would not be required. The C language has implicit conversions for **all** arithmetic types, albeit sometimes with implementation-defined behavior when the destination type is signed. Having a function take an unsigned argument and return a signed return value ensures that the caller doesn't have to worry about implementation-defined behavior (because either way, any conversion, if it happens, will be from signed to unsigned and thus well-defined).

Comment: @R..: well, to the extent (if any) that implementation-defined behavior of `write` is less worrying that implementation-defined behavior of a conversion, the caller doesn't have to worry.

Comment: @R..: there may be implicit conversions, but wouldn't it be likely to trigger warnings in compilers/lint etc?

Answer (score 2):

By making the parameter unsigned it removes the need for the function to check for nonsensical negative requests.

Answer (score 1):

`write` can only write from a single contiguous array of `unsigned char`, which cannot be larger than `PTRDIFF_MAX`, which is (on all real-world POSIX systems, and perhaps this is required by POSIX too...?) equal to `SIZE_MAX/2`. Thus passing a value which would be negative if interpreted as a signed value is a programming error to begin with - the passed size does not agree with the available space in the buffer.

In theory `readv` and `writev` could perform IO operations larger than `SIZE_MAX/2` by repeating the same `iov` buffers multiple times in the array, but if I remember correctly, they're specified to fail if the total size would be greater than `SSIZE_MAX`.